# How to install autodiscover redirect for Exchange(?)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, dns, exchange, domain

I'm seriously confused about a client's request. Actually the request comes from another IT service provider (I'm replacing the actual domain with example.com / example2.com).

> Create a subdomain autodiscover.example.com that redirects to mail.example2.com. This subdomain MUST ONLY be reachable on port 80.

I found out that this requirement is from some client configuration workflow for Outlook/Exchange (?, I'm not very versed in MS Mail stuff).
Source is this [Autodiscover - Grundlagen](https://www.msxfaq.de/exchange/autodiscover/autodiscover_grundlagen.htm) German site.

Now I really don't know how to achieve this. The current host for example.com is 1&1, a website is on shared hosting. I actually just bought a Managed Cloud Server, because I thought I could configure a firewall, but apparently this is only possible on not managed Cloud Servers.

If it is possible? if I do: Switch package from managed or get support to block port 443 (or essentially everything except 80)?

Then what to do with the domain? Like...this?

- set autodiscover.example.com A/AAAA record to IP of Cloud Server, MX    example.com to mail.example2.com, SPF includes mail.example2.com
- set redirect for autodiscover.example.com as 301
- Keep example.com A/AAAA on old shared hosting

Is this correct? SSL for the website should still be possible? Whatever dark magic ritual Microsoft does would function?

And for my personal peace of mind: is this whole effort (and at least 180 € additional cost per year) really necessary?

And how can I test the setup without any control over whatever is at mail.example2.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an additional website in the Client Access Server that listens on port 80, intercepts redirection traffic and sends it to the original autodiscover URL. 
For details,https://jaapwesselius.com/2011/08/28/autodiscover-redirect-srv-record/